# How to avoid that anytime(<numeric>) "updates by reference"?

Tags: r, date, datetime, posixct

I want to convert a numeric variable to `POSIXct` using `anytime`. My issue is that `anytime(<numeric>)` converts the input variable as well - I want to keep it.

Simple example:

```
library(anytime)
t_num <- 1529734500
anytime(t_num)
# [1] "2018-06-23 08:15:00 CEST"
t_num
# [1] "2018-06-23 08:15:00 CEST"
```

This differs from the 'non-update by reference' behaviour of `as.POSIXct` in `base` R:

```
t_num <- 1529734500
as.POSIXct(t_num, origin = "1970-01-01")
# [1] "2018-06-23 08:15:00 CEST"
t_num
# 1529734500
```

---

Similarly, `anydate(<numeric>)` also updates by reference:

```
d_num <- 17707
anydate(d_num)
# [1] "2018-06-25"
d_num
# [1] "2018-06-25"
```

---

I can't find an explicit description of this behaviour in `?anytime`. I could use `as.POSIXct` as above, but does anyone know how to handle this within `anytime`?

Comment: Just noticing your `t_num` is not _really_ real (e.g. `data.table:::isReallyReal(t_num)`), i.e., you can just replace it with `1529734500L` :)

Comment: just that `class(1529734500)` is `numeric` but `class(1529734500L)` is not, so you can eschew the `1*`/`0+` kludges by starting with an integer

Comment: Enforcing the 'it is a cast so you get a copy'.  And of course 1529734500 _is_ `numeric`, but as you point, `data.table` reminds us we can express _the same value_ using an `integer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hack it like this:

```
library(anytime)
t_num <- 1529734500
anytime(t_num+0)
# POSIXct[1:1], format: "2018-06-23 08:15:00"
t_num
# [1] 1529734500
```

Note that an integer input will be treated differently:

```
t_int <- 1529734500L
anytime(t_int)
# POSIXct[1:1], format: "2018-06-23 08:15:00"
t_int
# [1] 1529734500
```

Comment: Yes, good answer too.  See my (later) answer and comments as to why.

Answer (score 10):

`anytime` author here:  this is standard R and Rcpp and passing-by-`SEXP` behaviour:  you cannot protect a `SEXP` being passed from being changed.

The view that `anytime` takes is that *you are asking for an input to be converted to a `POSIXct`* as that is what `anytime` does: from char, from int, from factor, from anything.  As a `POSIXct` really *is* a numeric value (plus a S3 class attribute) this is what you are getting.

If you do not want this (counter to the design of `anytime`) you can do what @Moody_Mudskipper and @PKumar showed: used a temporary expression (or variable).

(I also think the `data.table` example is a little unfair as `data.table` -- just like `Rcpp` -- is very explicit about taking references where it can. So of course it refers back to the original variable.  There are idioms for deep copy if you need them.)

Lastly, an obvious trick is to use `format` if you just want different display:

```
R> d <- data.frame(t_num=1529734500)
R> d[1, "posixct"] <- format(anytime::anytime(d[1, "t_num"]))
R> d
       t_num             posixct
1 1529734500 2018-06-23 01:15:00
R>
```

That would work the same way in `data.table`, of course, as the string representation is a type change. Ditto for `IDate` / `ITime`.

*Edit:* And the development version in the Github repo has had functionality to preserve the incoming argument since June 2017.  So the next CRAN version, whenever I will push it, will have it too.

Comment: See my updated answer showing that it works differently with integer inputs

Comment: Great explanation, especially for understanding why this only affects _numeric_ input to `anytime`. It would be helpful to add this to `?anytime`.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: That is _precisely_ the gotcha example we have shown a number of times with `Rcpp`:  input of `int` to `numeric` function does a cast, hence a copy, hence no change on (now copied) input!

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Sure. Where? Under 'Details' ?

Comment: maybe Note? and/or a quick example: `t = 0; anytime(t); t`

Comment: @Dirk what about a `numbyref` logical argument to make it 100% explicit ?

Comment: @Henrik: As I tried to explain, that is _baked into_ R and Rcpp: int and char are different types, and when `POSIXct` comes out at the end they are not affected as they are distinct copies -- `numeric` gets converted for efficiency reasons. You generally do not want spurious copies.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: No, not worth it.  We very rarely see `numeric` as input anyway.

Comment: Given this inconsistency, any reason not to throw `is.numeric` cases into `.POSIXct`? From what I can tell the speed is ~ the same.

Comment: It is not an inconsistency. It is design (of R and its `SEXP`), and how a typed language works.

Comment: One small question Dirk: In the light of "_It is design (of R and its SEXP) and how a typed language works_", do you mind to elaborate on the difference in update-by-reference behavior between `anytime(<numeric>)` and its `base` analogue `as.POSIXct(<numeric>)`? To me, this may seem more like a design choice of `anytime` (rather than of R and its SEXP)? Which would be perfectly fine! Cheers

Comment: `POSIXct` is not a native `SEXP` type; it is a `numeric` with an S3 class attribute.  Hence "basically the same" at the C++ level,

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel FYI, I removed the `data.table` stuff from my Q (not needed to illustrate my point), so you may want to do a corresponding edit of your answer. Cheers

Comment: The observed behavior for non-`numeric` vs. `numeric` input is different. That's the very definition of inconsistency (whether it's by design or not is orthogonal). Anyway as long as it's clearly stated in the documentation the design is up to you.

Comment: I just tried to look into adding this functionality and ... realized younger me already did a year ago.  Just use the development version from github.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! I assume you didn't see my 'self-answer' when you made your edit ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you do this, it will work :

```
t_num <- 1529734500
anytime(t_num*1)

#> anytime(t_num*1)
#[1] "2018-06-23 06:15:00 UTC"
#> t_num
#[1] 1529734500
```

Answer (score 2):

Any reason to be married to `anytime`?

```
.POSIXct(t_num, tz = 'Europe/Berlin')
# [1] "2018-06-23 08:15:00 CEST"
```

`.POSIXct(x, tz)` is a wrapper for `structure(x, class = c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt'), tzone = tz)` (i.e. you can ignore declaring the origin), and is essentially `as.POSIXct.numeric` (except the latter is flexible in allowing non-UTC origin dates), look at `print(as.POSIXct.numeric)`.

Answer (score 2):

When I did my homework before posting the question, I checked the [*open* `anytime` issues](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues). I have now browsed the *closed* ones as well, where I found exactly the same issue as mine:

[anytime is overwriting inputs](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/issues/68)

There the package author writes:

> I presume because `as.POSIXct()` leaves its input alone, we should too?

So from [`anytime version 0.3.1 (unreleased)`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/commit/f88d6fede8cd8c1a7e7cfd222ff6030c8daf6797):

> Numeric input is now preserved rather than silently cast to the return object type

---

Thus, one answer to my question is: "wait for `0.3.1`"*.

When `0.3.1` is released, the behaviour of `anytime(<numeric>)` will agree with `anytime(<non-numeric>)` and `as.POSIXct(<numeric>)`, and work-arounds not needed.

---

*Didn't have to wait too long: [0.3.1 is now released](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/anytime/): "*Numeric input is now preserved rather than silently cast to the return object type*"